# Cant login to Sql WorkBench as I forgot my root password

Tags: mysql, sqlyog, sql-workbench-j

I have forgotten my root@localhost password for MySQL and because of this, I am unable to connect to the database. How do I change it?. I tried the Alter method in which we have to set a new password in a txt file and then run. I tried that but it's still not changing.

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Hello @ArnabDas, are you using **Xampp** or it is stand-along MySQL?

Comment: See if the [information here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password-windows-linux) can help.

Comment: @AwatITWork I am using Standalone MySQL

Comment: @PaulT. I had visited this page but didn't help

Comment: @ArnabDas, can you share a screenshot of your installation folder, and locate the **MySQL** and **bin**, also are you using Windows operating system, and your user is the administator?

Comment: Please refer to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password-in-windows-using-cmd/

Answer (score 0):

if you have an Administrator user, then you can reset the MySQL root password using
**sysvar_init_file** or **init_file** for short, here is how you can do it.

**First,** you have to **Stop** MySQL service, open Service and find MySQL Service and stop it.

**Next,** create an empty text file and put this, save it anywhere on your computer, let's say Desktop:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
```

**Next,** copy the file path you have created and navigate to your **Bin** folder where you have installed your MySQL on your computer.

```
"C:\Users\Awat\Desktop\MySQL Root Reset\rootReset.txt"
```

default similar to this one:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server Version\bin
```

**After that,** open CMD or Powershell as **administrator** and navigate to the installation folder and **Bin**

Type the following command, like me assuming you are in the **Bin** folder already

```
mysqld.exe --init-file="C:\Users\Awat\Desktop\MySQL Root Reset\rootReset.txt"
```

Please tell me if you have trouble implementing this.